# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, referenceerror

I am using jQuery. This is my coding on my main page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"> 
</script>
```

and my script.js is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
     $("#title").click(function () {
        alert("Works!");
    });
});
```

My full coding can be found here: http://pastie.org/8676656.

Using a tool on the browser, I found an error in my javascript code:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
```

on line:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you include jQuery

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have to import jQuery before using it:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Notice it is using `//` as protocol (not `http://` or `https://`), it means: if your .html file is at a `http://` server, it will get jQuery from `http://ajax.google...`, and if it is at a `https://` server, it will get it from `https://ajax.google...`.

**Note**: If, while developing, you open your HTML file in your browser instead of in a server, you should specify the protocol, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16509764/1850609), otherwise it won't work:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also, you should, if possible, place your .js files at the bottom of the page, right before closing `</body>`. See more in [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom).

Comment: Thanks! I tried to use a link for jquery before but it was a different one.

Comment: @user3155807 if this or any of the answers solved your problem please accept the appropriate answer.

Comment: @Geo just had to wait the required 15 mins

Comment: @user3155807 apologies then, I forgot about the time limits.

Comment: Key note in the answer is **before**. If you import jQuery after your code, it will not be recognized.

Answer (score 3):

Import jQuery before your code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: closing tag should be </script>

Answer (score 2):

Include **jQuery** before your script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is jquery load problem,
load jquery before all your code and script.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```