# Ui range slider is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't know what's wrong. This code is correct but when I run it in my local machine I recognize that the input field is missing! 
 
[image]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>slider demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>jQuery Mobile Example</h1>
  </div>
  <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <label for="slider-0">Input slider:</label>
    <input type="range" name="slider-0" id="slider-0" value="60" min="0" max="100">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you imported resources in proper order?

Comment: I can see the input field when running your snippet. Does it really result in that screenshot on your end?

Comment: yes, that's really strange !! :((

Answer (score 0):

You need to set protocol because by default browser will set file://

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

**IMPORTANT - it is a bad practise to specify the protocol, use this only on local machine**

Comment: Its a bad practice to specify protocols. Ideally it should pick the protocol of your website.

Comment: @Rajesh It is true but it won't work on local machine. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509740/why-jquery-does-not-work-on-my-home-local-machine

Comment: @Luka Thats correct. If you browse local file, without server, it will not work. Please do mention this in your answer. This might help someone facing similar problem.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>slider demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>jQuery Mobile Example</h1>
  </div>
  <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <label for="slider-0">Input slider:</label>
    <input type="range" name="slider-0" id="slider-0" value="60" min="0" max="100">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please explain what you have changed. Just putting working code is not enough.

Comment: @Rajesh he changed the order of including scripts as I did in answer above

Comment: @Rajesh I corrected the url with http protocol. I did not see that someone already answered it as my code snippet was  open.

Comment: @Luka I got that. The purpose of comment was, I had to read and compare entire code to understand what was changed. Ideally we should highlight points of correction/changes so OP and others can understand easily.